# ¿Quien me puede ayudar a construir esta tabla en html?

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, sql

Quiero mostrar una tabla en html de una consulta de la base de datos de tres tablas que se relacionan, las tablas estan estructuradas asi:

```
Restaurant | Platos      | Precios
-----------------------------------------
id         | id          | id
nombre     | nombre      | restaurant_id
           | descripcion | plato_id
           |             | precio
```

Donde la tabla que quiero mostrar esta estructurada de la siguiente manera:

```
platos  | restaurant 1 | restaurant 2 | restaurant 3 |
------------------------------------------------------
plato 1 | 10           | X o 0        | 15           |
plato 2 | X o 0        | 5,4          | 7            |
plato 3 | X o 0        | 12           | X o 0        |
plato 4 | 10           | 11,5         | 17           |
plato 5 | 6            | 6,5          | 10           |
```

donde aparece X o O es cuando ese restaurant no tiene precio de ese plato o no existe ese registro.

He intentado pero no me sale la tabla de ese modo, si alguien ya lo ha hecho o tiene una idea seria de gran ayuda. Gracias

El proyecto esta escrito con el framework laravel, las variables usadas ha sido estas:

obtengo una arreglo con todos los platos $platos

obtengo una arreglo con todos los restaurant $restaurant

y obtengo una arreglo de los precios $precios

el codigo html es:

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Platos</th>
   @foreach($restaurant as $res)
    <th>{{$res->nombre}}</th>
   @endforeach
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  @foreach($platos as $pla)
   <tr>
    <td>{{$pla->nombre}}</td>
    @foreach($restaurant as $res)
     @foreach($precios as $pre)
      @if($pre->restaurant_id==$res->id && $pre->plato_id==$pla->id)
       <td>{{$pre->precio}}</td>
      @else
       <td>0</td>
      @endif
     @endforach
    @endforach
   </tr>
  @endforeach
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Ese es el código utilizado, pero no funciona, no muestra los precios en el orden que corresponde a cada restaurant

Comment: Estaría bueno que dejes el código de lo que intentaste, para ayudarte a corregirlo!

Comment: Para ayudarte con tu pregunta, añade el código que utilizaste y te intentaremos ayudar en lo que podamos

Comment: creo que usas laravel?